# Convert Oracle SQL query to Spring JPA using IN a list of objects

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa

I am having trouble converting the following working SQL query to JPA:

```
SELECT a.* FROM TableA a1, TableB b1, TableC c1 WHERE
a1.c  = c1.c AND a1.b = b1.b AND 
(a1.attr1, b1.anotherAttrB, c1.anotherAttrC) IN (('2016','2004','678'), ('2020','2004','678'));
```

Heres the JPA query I tried, but fails:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT a FROM TableA a1, TableB b1, TableC c1 WHERE
 a1.c  = c1.c AND a1.b = b1.b AND
(a1.anotherAttrA, b1.anotherAttrB, c1.anotherAttrC) IN :myObjectList")
public List<A> findByMyObjectListIn(@Param("myObjectList") List<MyObject>myObjectList);
```

where MyObject is just a simple POJO with three Strings.

Any ideas out there?

Comment: Did you try, instead of having a List<MyObject> to have a List<List<String>> ? because Spring won't be able to know that you want to use MyObject as a list of 3 String

Comment: Thx Zinc - tried that but I get a
ORA-00920: invalid relational operator